# Retrieve user groups in google for work

Tags: security, google-oauth, google-openid, google-openidconnect

I'm building a backoffice aplication and want to leverage our companies Google for Work directory for authentication. Is there a way to retrieve the groups a user belongs to within the organization? Maybe to get them in the claims when authenticating via OpenId?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your question is a little unclear (what are you using to build your application? what exactly do you mean by "the groups a user belongs to"?), you can fairly easily retrieve user information using the [Directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users#get_user).

For actual authentication, you can [use Google as an Oauth identity provider](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6087519).

Comment: I'm using aspnet middleware for openID and what I meant with the "groups a user belongs to" was about which AD groups he's been assigned, and was wondering if there was a way of getting this info on the claims